# How can i deform the view in XNA at all sides in different directions?

Tags: c#, image, xna, texture2d

[this is the effect i want to apply to the entire view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naDZb.png)

I made a 2d side scroller game with a camera class that uses a Matrix to scale, rotate or create a perspective. The problem is, that i can only apply a perspective view in one direction using camera.transform.M21 etc., but i want all 4 corners to be deformed in different directions like you can see in the image. Any ideas how i can apply this effect to the whole view and not just for one image? I'm using C# with the Monogame library.

Comment: Have you thought about caching the rendered screen into a `RenderTarget2D`and apply a shader to it? This is probably the fastest thing you can do.

Comment: Just deform your vertices in your vertex shader